# Repeated speech in email compose window when using Voiceover

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, voiceover, mfmailcomposer

As Voiceover users attempt to dictate in an email compose window, their words are repeated back to them as they speak.

Although this does not happen in Mail, it does occur both in my complex shipped app, and in a very simple test app, which is just a default template with only this code added...

```
@interface ViewController  () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Has anyone seen this, and knows of a solution, or can confirm that it is an iOS bug? I see almost no similar reports of it around the web.

I do wonder if I am using Voiceover incorrectly, but I don't see a similar problem in Mail. Normal dictation into this window works fine (although I am seeing a stereo waveform displayed instead of the usual mono one at the moment- I'm not sure if that is relevant)

Comment: I have discovered that if you disable "typing feedback" (on the Voiceover page of settings) it stops this problem occurring. 

Unfortunately the user with the issue tells me they need that function enabled for other things, but it may be a useful clue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the behavior, but you have to do some weird things.  The only way I was able to get this to happen was by moving accessibility focus away and back into the composer view after enabling dictation.  This is a bug and since it's a bug contained in a bit of private API it's a bug you can't really work around.  In practice I would suspect that it's a bug that wouldn't show itself very frequently.

Comment: Thanks Chris, unfortunately my user tells me this problem occurs all the time for him.

Comment: A user with the wrong "habits" would hit this issue reliably.  But, other users may never run into it.